# Ruby on Rails tutorial destroy action results in show

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the tutorial and having an annoying problem when trying to delete/destroy a record in my model. The destroy action seems to result in a show action. A lot of the information online suggests it's a javascript problem but application.js already contains //= require jquery_ujs and //= require jquery.
(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

**index.html.erb**

```
         <h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
    <%= link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'articles' %>

    <h1>Listing articles</h1>
     <%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Ratings</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>

      <% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= article.title %></td>
          <td><%= article.text %></td>
          <td><%= article.genre %></td>
          <td><%= article.ratings %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
                  method: :delete,
                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>

    <%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def index
    @articles = Article.all
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

def new
     @article = Article.new
 end

 def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end


def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if 
    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end

end


def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

end

    private 

def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :genre, :ratings)
end
end
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :default, 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the browser console? I'm 99% sure it is a javascript problem.

Comment: Me too - it looks like you JS won't be present to support the `delete` method

Comment: This is the console output: GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/default.js 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this problem before...

--

It's basically because you've not included JQuery UJS in your application / layout.

Rails makes the `delete` method work by assigning some JS to change the request from [`GET` to `DELETE`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery#data-method-links-that-result-in-post-put-or-delete-requests) whenever you click it.

The main reason why `destroy` links don't work (yours is routing to `show`, which basically means it's using `GET` rather than `DELETE`) is because Rails is not translating your `method` properly:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

---

Some tips:

```
#app/views/articles/index.html.erb
<%= content_tag :h1, "Hello, Rails!" %>
<%= link_to 'My Blog', articles_path %>

<%= content_tag :h1, "Listing articles" %>
<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>

<%  attrs = %i(title text genre ratings) %>
<%= content_tag :table do %>
   <%= content_tag :tr do %>
       <% attrs.each do |attr| %>
          <%= content_tag :th, attr.to_s.titleize %>
       <% end %>
       <%= content_tag :th, "&nbsp;", colspan: 3 %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= content_tag :tr do %>
       <% attrs.each do |attr| %>
          <%= content_tag :td, article.send(attr) %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= content_tag :td, link_to('Show', article) %>
    <%= content_tag :td, link_to('Edit', edit_article_path(article)) %>
    <%= content_tag :td, link_to('Destroy', article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

You don't have to use `content_tag` at all, I just find it better to use it than vanilla HTML (makes sure any future code is supported).

Also, try your best to use `loops` wherever you can. So many people repeat code needlessly:

```
<td><%= @article.title %></td>
<td><%= @article.text %></td>
<td><%= @article.date %></td>
<td><%= @article.news %></td>
```

...

```
<% attrs = %i(title text date news) %>
<% attrs.each do |a| %>
   <td><%= @article.send a %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When I add <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> to my index file I get a typeError when refreshing my server.

Comment: ExecJS::ProgramError in Articles#index and complaining about line 6 i.e the "application" line

Comment: Install NodeJS on your system

Comment: Excellent! Worked. Thanks very much! Why did I need to do it? Is this part of a standard installization of Rails?

Comment: It's something to do with how Rails handles javascript. There's meant to be another way to fix it, but I just install Node and it works. `ExecJS` errors are almost always caused by this problem ^_^